# Load streaming audio file html5 audio player

Tags: html, audio, go, reactjs, streaming

I've written a service in golang with two endpoints - one requires the user to authorize in order to access it - the other requires no authorization.

I'm retrieving a stream from a music streaming API on the server and writing it back to the client as a response in both cases.

The content type on the response in both cases seems to be application/octet-stream. I've tried setting the content type to audio/mpeg but it seems to make no difference.

When I try to call load on the html5 audio player I'm using (just the straight up  element) after setting the source to the return of my web service call to the response from the service, I get an error - undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Here's how I'm retrieving the stream :

```
callApi: function() {
$.ajax({
  context: this,
  url: 'http://localhost:3001/secured/ping',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  alert("The request to the secured endpoint was successful");
  this.setState({audioSrc: data});
  this.refs.audio.play();
}, function() {
  alert("You need to download the server seed and start it to call this API");
});
```

}

The HTML5 audio element looks like -

```html
<div className="logged-in-box auth0-box logged-in">
          <h1 id="logo"><img src="https://cdn.auth0.com/blog/auth0_logo_final_blue_RGB.png" /></h1>
          <audio ref="audio" src={this.state.audioSrc} autoPlay controls></audio>
          <img src={this.state.profile.picture} />
          <h2>Welcome {this.state.profile.nickname}</h2>
          <button onClick={this.callApi} className="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Call API</button>
        </div>
```

I'm using react as the client side framework for data binding etc... I'm not sure what that error is all about however I have a feeling it has to do with my response coming back as binary which the audio player can't handle.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Binary is not an audio format it's a numbering scheme.  You should figure out what format (Content-Type) your server is returning for the request.  Make sure the server is returning the file your expecting and go from there.  Maybe for starters just see if you can load the file off the server without any authentication in place.

Comment: Seeing the Go source for this would probably prove to be helpful.  As @Sean mentioned, you need to set the correct `Content-Type` header in your proxied response.  You can do this pretty easily by just reading some of the headers from the response from the external service and including them in your response.